# How to push a variable's value into a vector but keep the variable alive?

Tags: rust, vector, clone, borrow

I got a question about how to `move` a variable into a vector but without destroying this variable because it has to be reused in a loop. Below shows what I mean:

```
type Letter = char;
type LetterSet = Vec<Letter>;

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::<LetterSet>::new();
    let mut letterset: LetterSet = LetterSet::new(); 

    for i in 0..5 {
        let a = (48 + i as u8) as char;
        letterset.push(a);
        if i % 2 == 1 {
            let b = (65 + i as u8) as char;
            letterset.push(b); 
        } else {
            let c = (97 + i as u8) as char;
            letterset.push(c);
        }
        v.push(letterset.clone());
        letterset.clear();
    }

    for letterset in v {
        for letter in letterset {
            print!("{} ", letter);
        }
        println!("");
    } 
}
```

The code above runs. However, I want to avoid `clone` in

```
        v.push(letterset.clone());
        letterset.clear();
```

since `letterset` will be cleared anyways. Rather, I want to move its contents into `v`  but keep it alive, because `letterset` has to be for the next iteration.

I tried to remove `.clone()` but obviously this results in a 'borrow after move' error. I wonder how to do it, thanks.

Comment: Since we are talking about `Vec<char>`, the `.clone()` will almost certainly compile to an allocation (which you can't avoid) and a single `memcpy()`. I don't really see any reason to avoid the `.clone()`. To answer the question: You can `v.push(letterset.drain(..).collect())`, which will move the owned elements from `letterset` into the new `Vec` without duplicating them, leaving a cleared `letterset` behind. Again, this would only matter if `Letter` was more heavy than a simple `char`.

Comment: @user2722968 thanks for your comment. My understanding of `clone` (if correct) is that it will heap allocate and duplicate the resource before `letterset` gets cleared. Yes, in reality `Letter` is much heavier than the toy example.

Comment: In that case, the `letterset.clone()` will clone the `Vec` and all it's content, before throwing the original away; again, in case of `char` this is dirt-cheap an not worth the hassle. The `.drain()`-thingy will avoid the clone, because it moves `Letter` into its new location directly. Also look at the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new LetterSet at every iteration? Moving a Vec is only moving references to the heap, it's pretty cheap.

If you really want to re-use the same var you can use `std::mem::take` which will return the Vec and replace the original variable by its default (an empty  vec) - this has the same behaviour since you're making a new Vec every time.

```rust
v.push(std::mem::take(&mut letterset));
```

You can also skip `.clear()` since it'll be already empty.

Comment: Note that replacing the `Vec` with its `Default` instead of calling `.clear()` on it will use a new, empty allocation instead of re-using the old capacity.

Comment: The old capacity is still being used since it was moved to `v` - it did not copy it.

Comment: The point being that `lettershop` is being pushed to, while the `Vec` in `v` is probably not. So after the `take()`, the very next all to `lettershop.push` is guaranteed to cause an allocation.

Comment: It has no choice to allocate, `v` is a `Vec<Vec<char>>` and the storage used by `letterset` (`Vec<char>`) is being moved since the entire Vec is pushed to `v` (note: it's not appended, the whole vector is the element). The memory has to live somewhere, either it's moved to the inner Vec, or it's cloned before being cleared.

Comment: @Mathieu Rene, thanks for the suggestion. `letterset` has to be outside of the loop; it serves as a cache for multiple iterations of the loop.

Comment: @foehn does `mem::take` or `mem::swap` work for you then?

Comment: @Mathieu Rene `v.push(std::mem::take(&mut letterset));` looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply move the `letterset` initialization into the inner loop:

```
for i in 0..5 {
    let mut letterset: LetterSet = LetterSet::new(); 
    let a = (48 + i as u8) as char;
    letterset.push(a);
    if i % 2 == 1 {
        let b = (65 + i as u8) as char;
        letterset.push(b); 
    } else {
        let c = (97 + i as u8) as char;
        letterset.push(c);
    }
    v.push(letterset);
}
```

Or eliminate it entirely:

```
for i in 0..5 {
    let a = (48 + i as u8) as char;
    let b = (65 + i as u8) as char;
    let c = (97 + i as u8) as char;
    v.push(vec![a, if i % 2 == 1 { b } else { c }]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @orlp. I cannot initialize `letterset` in the loop. This example is oversimplified. Actually, I work on a key-sorted table, where multiple lines may have the same key, and I need to process the data for each key, not for each line.